# Not able to Delete AWS VPC using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, vpc

```
`---
```

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
      - group_vars/delete-vpc.yml
  vars:
      region: ap-south-1
      aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  tasks:
    - name: delete the vpc
      ec2_vpc_net:
         name: test-vpc
         cidr_block: 10.22.0.0/16
         region: ap-south-1
         aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
         aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"

## profile: "{{ build_env.profile }}"

```
     state: absent
```

## tenancy: dedicated

```
     purge_cidrs: yes
  register: vpc_delete`
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: true
  vars_files:
      - group_vars/delete-vpc.yml
  vars:
      region: ap-south-1
      aws_access_key: "{{ aws_access_key }}"
      aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_secret_key }}"
  tasks:
    - name: delete the vpc
      ec2_vpc_net:
         name: test-vpc
         cidr_block: 10.22.0.0/16
         region: ap-south-1
         aws_access_key: "{{aws_access_key}}"
         aws_secret_key: "{{aws_secret_key}}"
         state: absent
         purge_cidrs: yes
      register: vpc_delete
```

Comment: here is the error : "msg": "Failed to delete VPC  You may want to use the ec2_vpc_subnet, ec2_vpc_igw, and/or ec2_vpc_route_table modules to ensure the other components are absent.: An error occurred (DependencyViolation) when calling the DeleteVpc operation: The vpc has dependencies and cannot be deleted

Comment: but when i delete the vpc from AWS console it does not ask me to delete the subnets, route tables etc.., not sure why its asking us to delete the dependencies whicle executing through commandline?

Comment: @NaveenSangadala the AWS console is essentially an application that talks to the AWS APIs.  It iterates through the dependendencies and makes the necessary API calls to remove them.  (You can observe this with CloudTrail logs.)  The difference is documented: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/working-with-vpcs.html#VPC_Deleting

Comment: HI Micheal, i completely agree what you said , VPC will be having dependencies like subnets, instances, gateways, etc... ,actually instances which attached to the vpc were already got terminated through ansible-playbook, and it was trying to delete the vpc , but its not getting deleted, but when i use the AWS console to delete the VPC it will just ask for the confirmation that all the dependencies will be deleted once I click the submit button. so the same settings how can i apply the same in my ansible playbook to delete the VPC ?